# regex start and close characters (preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex

I have both googled and searched this site before posting here, but I can't seem to understand the start and close regex characters within the following code segment.

```
$url = preg_replace('|[^...]|i', '', $url)
```

I am familiar with `'/.../i'`, but what does `'|...|i'` mean ? Thanks in advance.

ps - this is my first question on this forum, so please be forgiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'|...|i'` is just the same as `'/.../i'`, the difference is , you don't have to escape the `/` inside `'|...|i'`, but have to escape `|`.

**A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.**

***[SEE THE DOC>](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)***

Comment: Wow... that was quicker than I expected! Thanks. Sadly, I wasn't able to fully comprehend the difference yet. Would you be kind enough to elaborate on "you don't have to escape the / inside '|...|i', but have to escape |."